# Angular Kendo line chart does not plot after pushing json data to array

Tags: javascript, angular, kendo-ui

I have a JSON format data coming from backend it looks like this on my console,and i can plot it

```
(10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {windSpeed: 7.85, timeStamp: "2020-06-07-11:59"}
1: {windSpeed: 10.23, timeStamp: "2020-06-07-12:09"}
2: {windSpeed: 9.34, timeStamp: "2020-06-07-12:19"}
3: {windSpeed: 11.24, timeStamp: "2020-06-07-12:29"}
4: {windSpeed: 9.32, timeStamp: "2020-06-07-12:39"}
5: {windSpeed: 10.12, timeStamp: "2020-06-07-12:49"}
6: {windSpeed: 8.63, timeStamp: "2020-06-07-12:59"}
7: {windSpeed: 10.97, timeStamp: "2020-06-07-13:09"}
8: {windSpeed: 11.41, timeStamp: "2020-06-07-13:19"}
9: {windSpeed: 9.69, timeStamp: "2020-06-07-13:29"}
```

when I push this data in an array then I cant plot the chart, here is my array:

```
public series:any[]=[];
```

and when i push the json:

```
  this.series.push(this.JsonData);
```

i get the data format in console like:

```
[Array(10)]
0: Array(10)
0: {windSpeed: 7.85, timeStamp: "2020-06-07-11:59"}
1: {windSpeed: 10.23, timeStamp: "2020-06-07-12:09"}
2: {windSpeed: 9.34, timeStamp: "2020-06-07-12:19"}
3: {windSpeed: 11.24, timeStamp: "2020-06-07-12:29"}
4: {windSpeed: 9.32, timeStamp: "2020-06-07-12:39"}
5: {windSpeed: 10.12, timeStamp: "2020-06-07-12:49"}
6: {windSpeed: 8.63, timeStamp: "2020-06-07-12:59"}
7: {windSpeed: 10.97, timeStamp: "2020-06-07-13:09"}
 8: {windSpeed: 11.41, timeStamp: "2020-06-07-13:19"}
9: {windSpeed: 9.69, timeStamp: "2020-06-07-13:29"}
```

this format does not plot the chart ,any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor. Post CODE, Not CONSOLE.LOG of code

Comment: if `JsonData` is an array, you're pushing an array to an array. you likely want to `concat` instead, otherwise you're providing a matrix instead of a 1 dimention array.

Comment: @mplungjan actually, I feel this is quite guessable (from the logs above). Of course it would be far better with a reproducible example, but that's still understandable imho.

Comment: @briosheje concat does not work,and i need to push it because i need to compare many plot via multiselectDropDown,in this case i need to push into an array to keep track of them

Comment: `concat` returns a new array, so be sure to properly override the original one, otherwise (of course) it won't work.
It's quite unclear at this point, however, what you need to do.

Comment: @briosheje imagine you have a multiselect box,which has 10 diffrent cars!above it you have a chart which plot the power of the car upon multiselect dropdownlist,when you select the second item from the multiselect the first plot should be kept in the chart and second of should be plotted in order to compare with first one,thats why i need a array to push

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are pushing an array A (your "JsonData") into array B (your "series").
What you want to do is to pushed the ITEMS from array A into array B:

This can be achieved, for example, using the [Spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/Operatory/Spread_operator):

```
this.series.push(...this.JsonData);
```

Comment: this gives me the right format but strange thing is i cant plot it!i still can plot json but not array!